# How do I need to add a Json file according to these code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reference, postman

Hi everyone I dont know how to add json file according to these codes.
I want to create a user which contains name, surname, age, tel, mevki_id, city and town.

Note : city and town means in turkish  *il* and *ilce*.

Here my code :

User Schema :

```
var userSchema = Mongoose.Schema({ 

    name:{type: String,require:true},
    surname: {type: String,require:true},
    tel: {type: String,require:true},
    age: {type: String,require:true},
    mevki_id: {type: String,require:true},
    location_id : { type : Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'locations'}
```

Location Schema :

```
var LocationSchema = Mongoose.Schema ({

    il: {type: String, require:true},

    ilce: {type:String, require:true}   

});
```

User Controller :

```
this.createUser = function (req, res, next) {


      user.name = req.body.name;
        user.surname = req.body.surname;
        user.tel = req.body.tel;
        user.age = req.body.age;
        user.mevki_id= req.body.mevki_id;           
      user.location_id=location._id.id;

 user.save(function(err, result) {


        if (err) {

            return res.send({'error':err}); 
        }
        else {
    return res.send({'result':result,'status':'successfully saved'});
  }
    });
};
```

What kind of a json file that I need to insert with postman ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want the JSON file to add users to your database?

Comment: yeah I want to this but I dont know  actually I wonder that how to add document city and town information to user because there is no city and data in userschema  , they are in the location schema  So what kind of add json file to my database ? thnks  :)

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty clear that your POST query data should be send in this format:

```
{
    name: 'name',
    surname: 'surname',
    tel: 'tel',
    age: 'age',
    mevki_id: 'mevki_id',
    location_id: 'location_id'
}
```

I can't realy tell for the `location._id.id` variable in your controller because you don't show where it come from (earlyer in code ?), but you need to pass a locations *id* as a reference to a location present in the database, accordingly to the *userSchema* `location_id` type.
This *id* is an *ObjectId* reference for a location defined from *LocationSchema*.
You can omit this element as it is not *required* in the schema.

Keep in mind schema is just a structure of your data, not the data itself.

Comment: I really thnk u TGrif u are really helpful person

Comment: If you want to thank him, remember to validate the answer ;)